# kcfinder have upload directory selected through URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, kcfinder

**Problem:** As found in kcfinder's definition I am using this link to open kcfinder:

```
window.open('/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files&dir=files/public&subDir=/PO/200836', 'kcfinder_textbox',
            ', width=800, height=600');
```

In here, I have modified the URL to also include the subdirectory path so that the URL becomes something like this `http://192.168.212.200/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files&dir=files/public&subDir=/PO/200836` .

The `subDir` part has the directory name to be set to (and created if not exists). In the config.php I already have a directory set to be the root. So if the `subDir` is provided it will create the `subDir` inside the root of config.php. Now I would want this subDir to be the new root directory for kcfinder.

For example if my `uploadURL` in the config is `/var/www/html/web/upload/` the new root for the above URL should become `/var/www/html/web/upload/PO/200836/`.

**Attempt:** I have been able to successfully create the directory `/var/www/html/web/upload/PO/200836/` for the above URL (or any URL) provided. However, the root in kcfinder is still set to `/var/www/html/web/upload/`. So when I open the kcfinder, the directory gets created internally but the root is still set to the original root from config.php.

I added the following lines to change my root directory to the sub directory I pass through URL:

```
$this->config["uploadURL"] .= $_GET['subDir'];
$this->config["uploadDir"] .= $_GET['subDir'];
$this->typeDir = $this->config["uploadDir"] ."/files";
$this->typeURL = $this->config["uploadURL"] ."/files";
```

I have also raised this as an [issue](https://github.com/sunhater/kcfinder/issues/109) on github but no response from there yet. I am assuming the only change I need to do is set the root directory to display to the new directory being created but I am not sure where I am supposed to do this.

Is there a workaround for this?

PS: I am also open to any other *open source* web file manager PHP/jQuery solutions which has a way to do this. Using symfony as the framework.

**UPDATE:** I have tried replacing the default folder to the new modified folder like this in the `__construct()` of `upload.php`.

```
public function __construct() {

    // SET CMS INTEGRATION PROPERTY
    if (isset($_GET['cms']) &&
        $this->checkFilename($_GET['cms']) &&
        is_file("integration/{$_GET['cms']}.php")
    )
        $this->cms = $_GET['cms'];

    // LINKING UPLOADED FILE
    if (count($_FILES))
        $this->file = &$_FILES[key($_FILES)];

    // CONFIG & SESSION SETUP
    $session = new session("conf/config.php");
    $this->config = $session->getConfig();
    $this->session = &$session->values;
    $this->config["uploadURL"] .= $_GET["subDir"];


    // IMAGE DRIVER INIT
    if (isset($this->config['imageDriversPriority'])) {
        $this->config['imageDriversPriority'] =
            text::clearWhitespaces($this->config['imageDriversPriority']);
        $driver = image::getDriver(explode(' ', $this->config['imageDriversPriority']));
        if ($driver !== false)
            $this->imageDriver = $driver;
    }
    if ((!isset($driver) || ($driver === false)) &&
        (image::getDriver(array($this->imageDriver)) === false)
    )
        $this->backMsg("Cannot find any of the supported PHP image extensions!");

    // WATERMARK INIT
    if (isset($this->config['watermark']) && is_string($this->config['watermark']))
        $this->config['watermark'] = array('file' => $this->config['watermark']);

    // GET TYPE DIRECTORY
    $this->types = &$this->config['types'];
    $firstType = array_keys($this->types);
    $firstType = $firstType[0];
    $this->type = (
        isset($_GET['type']) &&
        isset($this->types[$_GET['type']])
    )
        ? $_GET['type'] : $firstType;

    // LOAD TYPE DIRECTORY SPECIFIC CONFIGURATION IF EXISTS
    if (is_array($this->types[$this->type])) {
        foreach ($this->types[$this->type] as $key => $val)
            if (in_array($key, $this->typeSettings))
                $this->config[$key] = $val;
        $this->types[$this->type] = isset($this->types[$this->type]['type'])
            ? $this->types[$this->type]['type'] : "";
    }

    // COOKIES INIT
    $ip = '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)';
    $ip = '/^' . implode('\.', array($ip, $ip, $ip, $ip)) . '$/';
    if (preg_match($ip, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ||
        preg_match('/^[^\.]+$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
    )
        $this->config['cookieDomain'] = "";
    elseif (!strlen($this->config['cookieDomain']))
        $this->config['cookieDomain'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    if (!strlen($this->config['cookiePath']))
        $this->config['cookiePath'] = "/";

    // UPLOAD FOLDER INIT

    // FULL URL
    if (preg_match('/^([a-z]+)\:\/\/([^\/^\:]+)(\:(\d+))?\/(.+)\/?$/',
            $this->config['uploadURL'], $patt)
    ) {
        list($unused, $protocol, $domain, $unused, $port, $path) = $patt;
        $path = path::normalize($path);
        $this->config['uploadURL'] = "$protocol://$domain" . (strlen($port) ? ":$port" : "") . "/$path";
        $this->config['uploadDir'] = strlen($this->config['uploadDir'])
            ? path::normalize($this->config['uploadDir'])
            : path::url2fullPath("/$path");
        $this->typeDir = "{$this->config['uploadDir']}/{$this->type}";
        $this->typeURL = "{$this->config['uploadURL']}/{$this->type}";

    // SITE ROOT
    } elseif ($this->config['uploadURL'] == "/") {
        $this->config['uploadDir'] = strlen($this->config['uploadDir'])
            ? path::normalize($this->config['uploadDir'])
            : path::normalize(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
        $this->typeDir = "{$this->config['uploadDir']}/{$this->type}";
        $this->typeURL = "/{$this->type}";

    // ABSOLUTE & RELATIVE
    } else {
        $this->config['uploadURL'] = (substr($this->config['uploadURL'], 0, 1) === "/")
            ? path::normalize($this->config['uploadURL'])
            : path::rel2abs_url($this->config['uploadURL']);
        $this->config['uploadDir'] = strlen($this->config['uploadDir'])
            ? path::normalize($this->config['uploadDir'])
            : path::url2fullPath($this->config['uploadURL']);
        $this->typeDir = "{$this->config['uploadDir']}/{$this->type}";
        $this->typeURL = "{$this->config['uploadURL']}/{$this->type}";
    }

    // HOST APPLICATIONS INIT
    if (isset($_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'])) {
        $this->opener['name'] = "ckeditor";
        $this->opener['CKEditor'] = array('funcNum' => $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum']);

    } elseif (isset($_GET['opener'])) {
        $this->opener['name'] = $_GET['opener'];

        if ($_GET['opener'] == "tinymce") {
            if (!isset($this->config['_tinyMCEPath']) || !strlen($this->config['_tinyMCEPath']))
                $this->opener['name'] = false;

        } elseif ($_GET['opener'] == "tinymce4") {
            if (!isset($_GET['field']))
                $this->opener['name'] = false;
            else
                $this->opener['TinyMCE'] = array('field' => $_GET['field']);
        }

    } else
        $this->opener['name'] = false;

    // LOCALIZATION
    foreach ($this->langInputNames as $key)
        if (isset($_GET[$key]) &&
            preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z\._\-]*$/i', $_GET[$key]) &&
            file_exists("lang/" . strtolower($_GET[$key]) . ".php")
        ) {
            $this->lang = $_GET[$key];
            break;
        }
    $this->localize($this->lang);

    // IF BROWSER IS ENABLED
    if (!$this->config['disabled']) {

        // TRY TO CREATE UPLOAD DIRECTORY IF NOT EXISTS
        if (!$this->config['disabled'] && !is_dir($this->config['uploadDir']))
            @mkdir($this->config['uploadDir'], $this->config['dirPerms'], true);
        // CHECK & MAKE DEFAULT .htaccess
        if (isset($this->config['_check4htaccess']) &&
            $this->config['_check4htaccess']
        ) {
            $htaccess = "{$this->config['uploadDir']}/.htaccess";
            $original = $this->get_htaccess();
            if (!file_exists($htaccess)) {
                if (!@file_put_contents($htaccess, $original))
                    $this->backMsg("Cannot write to upload folder. {$this->config['uploadDir']}");
            } else {
                if (false === ($data = @file_get_contents($htaccess)))
                    $this->backMsg("Cannot read .htaccess");
                if (($data != $original) && !@file_put_contents($htaccess, $original))
                    $this->backMsg("Incorrect .htaccess file. Cannot rewrite it!");
            }
        }

        // CHECK & CREATE UPLOAD FOLDER
        if (!is_dir($this->typeDir)) {
            if (!mkdir($this->typeDir, $this->config['dirPerms']))
                $this->backMsg("Cannot create {dir} folder.", array('dir' => $this->type));
        } elseif (!is_readable($this->typeDir))
            $this->backMsg("Cannot read upload folder.");
    }
}
```

This creates the directory and everything but it does not set the root folder to the newly created folder. The folder is still set to the default root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer here, I came up with an alternative solution using a Symfony bundle called [EMElfinderBundle](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle) since KCFinder had used `$_GET` variables all over their code and I couldn't change it possibly everywhere. This bundle actually turned out to be a better bundle than kcfinder. For anyone using Symfony I would definitely recommend this.

In the bundle, all I did was add up the following lines in its `ElFinderConfigurationReader.php`

```
$dir="";
parse_str(parse_url($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->server->all()["HTTP_REFERER"])["query"]);
$driverOptions["path"] .= $dir;
```